# Select Dropdown not Passing Selected Values to Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, drop-down-menu

I am building a dropdown menu in React using a select dropdown.

or some reason, my selected value is not passing, it is passing the entire array instead of the value I selected on the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I pass the value that I selected via dropdown?

**Dropdown Code in React**

```
  <select
                className='add-cap-select'
                onChange={(value) => handleChangeForm('agent', value)}
              >
                {agents.map((agent) => (
                  <option id='agent' key={agent} value={form.agent}>
                    {agent}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>

      /**
   * Handles when the user changes any regular form entry
   * @param {String} prop
   * @param {String} value
   */
  const handleChangeForm = (prop, value) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [prop]: value
    })
  }
```

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-firefly-ot3ubn

Comment: yes this is exactly what i need to do!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution to do this

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [agent, setAgent] = useState({
    agent:'',
  });
  const handleChangeForm = event =>{
    console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value)
    setAgent({...agent,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
  }

  return (
    <select
                className='add-cap-select'
                name="agent"
                onChange={(event) => handleChangeForm(event)}
              >
               <option value="one">one</option>
               <option value="two">two</option>
               <option value="three">three</option>
              </select>
  );
}
```

you are passing agent and value both in handleFormChange, instead of this you can put the name in select, and from the event, you can get the name as well as value, here you are directly passing value which is event actually if you want to do in your solution then you can do like this -> value.target.value